# Publishing a value through PubSubClient

Tags: arduino, publish-subscribe, mqtt

I tried the following code to publish a value using Arduino onto Mosquitto broker. The code appears to be right but then as soon as I compile/verify, the following error is thrown. What's the cause and how do I overcome this problem?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>


#define CLIENTID "ArduinoSensor"
#define TOPICNAME "sensor/temperature"
#define POLLINTERVAL 120000

void callback(char topic, byte payload, unsigned int length){
//Do nothing as we are publishing ONLY.
}

byte mac [] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED} ;
byte server [] = { 85, 119, 83, 194 };
EthernetClient ethClient;
PubSubClient arduinoClient(server, 1883, callback, ethClient) ;
unsigned long boardTime = 0 ;
float sensedTemperature = 0;
char charTemperature [20];


void setup(void) {
Serial.begin(9600);
//Connect to the MQTT server - test.mosquitto.org
beginConnection() ;
}

//Initialise MQTT connection
void beginConnection() {
Serial.begin(9600);
Ethernet.begin(mac) ;   //using the address assigned through DHCP 
int connRC = arduinoClient.connect(CLIENTID) ;
if (!connRC) {
Serial.println(connRC) ;
Serial.println("Could not connect to MQTT Server");
Serial.println("Please reset the arduino to try again");
delay(100);
exit(-1);
}
else {
Serial.println("Connected to MQTT Server...");
}
}

void loop(void) {
boardTime = millis();
if ((boardTime % POLLINTERVAL) == 0) {
  getTemp();
  dtostrf(sensedTemperature,5,2,charTemperature) ;
  arduinoClient.publish(TOPICNAME, charTemperature) ;
}
}

void getTemp() {
// Send the command to get temperatures
delay(100);
sensedTemperature = analogRead(2);   //temperature sensor at analog pin 2 on Arduino.
delay(150);
}
```

Error Printed:

```
publisher:18: error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(char, byte, unsigned int) {aka void (*)(char, unsigned char, unsigned int)}' to 'void (*)(char*, uint8_t*, unsigned int) {aka void (*)(char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)}' [-fpermissive]

 PubSubClient arduinoClient(server, 1883, callback, ethClient) ;

C:\Users\Chetan\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PubSubClient\src/PubSubClient.h:98:4: error:   initializing argument 3 of 'PubSubClient::PubSubClient(uint8_t*, uint16_t, void (*)(char*, uint8_t*, unsigned int), Client&)' [-fpermissive]

    PubSubClient(uint8_t *, uint16_t, MQTT_CALLBACK_SIGNATURE,Client& client);

 ^

exit status 1
invalid conversion from 'void (*)(char, byte, unsigned int) {aka void (*)(char, unsigned char, unsigned int)}' to 'void (*)(char*, uint8_t*, unsigned int) {aka void (*)(char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)}' [-fpermissive]

In file included from C:\Users\Chetan\Desktop\publisher\publisher.ino:4:0:
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the signature of the callback function you are passing to the constructor is incorrect.

You have:

```
void callback(char topic, byte payload, unsigned int length){
```

It should be:

```
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
```

Note the `*` for the `topic` and `payload` arguments.